# How can i use the same behavior as react-router's Link on a function within functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React-router v5 and i want to use the same behavior as Link component

```
<form className="align-bottom d-flex align-baseline align-items-md-end form-inline float-right">
        
    ...
    <Button type="button" className={"align-center getStarted btn mx-0 "}
       onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()} onClick={signUpHandler}>
       <HeaderLink className={'excluded'}>Get started</HeaderLink>
    </Button>
    ...
       
</form>
```

i Don't want to wrap the get started button with Link because i want to check if the website is visited from small devices (then don't show a pop-up but inside an url) or desktop screen (then just show the pop-up).

Here is the login i tried so far when the get started button get clicked :

```
const Header = () => {
    ...
    const signUpHandler = () => {
        const mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 900px)')
        if (mql.matches) {
            // The viewport is less than 670px
            window.location.href = "/sign-up";
            // <Redirect to='/login' />
        } else {
            // The viewport is wider than 670px
            toggleVisibility(!isVisible);
            changeIsLogIn(false)
            // changeIsLogIn(isLogIn => false)
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

So, instead of `window.location.href = "/sign-up";` which will reload the entire screen(on small screens) i want just to redirect the user using react-router's Link like.

Any help or advice would appreciated guys , Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the available [Hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks), you will find [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), which will give you access to the [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) object. This object has a push function, which the **Link** component uses as well.

```
// import the useHistory hook from react-router
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const Header = () => {
  // get the history object with useHistory
  const history = useHistory();
  ...
  const signUpHandler = () => {
    ...
    // redirect user to the sign-up page
    history.push("/sign-up");
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: My bad i forget about useHistory , Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

use the useHistory() hook.

Here you have a good doccumentation:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    ...
    const signUpHandler = () => {
        const mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 900px)')
        if (mql.matches) {
            // The viewport is less than 670px
            history.push("/sign-up");
        } else {
            // The viewport is wider than 670px
            toggleVisibility(!isVisible);
            changeIsLogIn(false)
            // changeIsLogIn(isLogIn => false)
        }
    }
   ...
}
```